# Getting subscript our range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a find a number in another workbook then copy column 2 of the corresponding row into cell (B5) of the original document. The code itself runs but I keep getting a run time error subscript out of range.

```
Sub findsomething()

Dim rng As Range
Dim account As String
Dim rownumber As Long
Dim dehyp As Long
Dim wb As Workbook

account = Replace(Range("A5").Value, "-", "")
Set wb = Workbooks.Open( _
  "L:\PRS\CEPA\Chemicals Management Plan\!Overviews and Summaries\" & _
  "List-of-substances-in-the-third-phase-of-CMP-(2016-2021).xlsx")

Set rng = wb.Sheets("Substances List 2019").Columns(1).Find(What:=account, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Total usage").Cells(2, 5).Value = _
           wb.Sheets("Substances List 2019").Cells(rng.Row, 2).Value
End If

End Sub
```

I have looked through other stack over flow queries and it says vsubscript does not recognize excel constants, which I can not understand. So if any one could offer any solutions or an explanation to tell me how to fix the code, ti would be much appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like either `ThisWorkbook` doesn't have a sheet named "Total usage", or `wb` doesn't have a sheet named "Substances List 2019". Check for trailing spaces, typos, etc.

Comment: Yeah, that was weird, I copy pasted both of the names of the sheets and I guess one of them was wrong because it is working now. Thank you!

Comment: I lied @BigBen am getting the same error, I don't know why, even after copy pasting.

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: The "ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Total usage").Cells(2, 5).Value = _
           wb.Sheets("Substances List 2019").Cells(rng.Row, 2).Value" , but I have double checked that total usage and substances list 2019 are the right names.

Comment: Ok so try to eliminate potential problems. You can use the worksheet codename instead of `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Total usage")`. You can find the codename in the VB editor - there's the list of sheets in the top left corner. If you still get the error after that, then `"Substances List 2019"` is not the name of the sheet in `wb`.

Comment: @BigBen - yup - my mistake, I read it as `ActiveWorkbook` in my mind. Comment removed.

Comment: @CLR makes sense - original comment removed as well.

Comment: I too think first BigBen comment should address the cause. Try substituting `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Total usage").Cells(2, 5).Value = _
           wb.Sheets("Substances List 2019").Cells(rng.Row, 2).Value
` with `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Total usage").Cells(2, 5).Value =1` and see if the problem lies in "Substances List 2019" field. If its doesn't throw any error it must reside in `wb.Sheets("Substances List 2019").Cells(rng.Row, 2).Value`